# Python 'wrapper' around `dig` for easier TSIG signing of queries

Tags: python, python-2.x, networking, wrapper, child-process

I wrote this Python script as a utility script for me.  It's something that could be achieved in a simple shell script or alias, but it wasn't 'verbose' enough for me in that format, or customizable.

This script, basically, is just designed to take and process whether a specified DNS TSIG keyfile (necessary for 'signed' requests to DNS servers for different types of requests that need authentication/authorization to be processed) exists, and then calls out to `dig`, specifying the relevant `-k` filepath (either a filename, in which case it checks current directory, a full file path, or if no `-k` is provided then a hard-coded default path).

Basically, looking for feedback on how I could improve this.  Any and all feedback is appreciated.  (Just don't crucify me for making a more complicated Python script to do something a simple shell alias or script could do, please.)

---

**dig+key.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import os
import subprocess

DEV_DEBUG_MODE = False

CURRENT_WORKING_DIR = os.getcwd() + "/"

DEFAULT_TSIG_MD5_KEYFILE = "/path/to/tsig/keyfile"


# noinspection PyClassHasNoInit
class _Errors:
    class KeyfilePathIssue(IOError):
        """Error that triggers only when an issue occurred with regards to the specified keyfile"""

        def __init__(self, custommsg):
            if custommsg:
                self.msg = custommsg
            else:
                self.msg = self.message

        def __str__(self):
            return self.msg

    class NoDigBinaryFound(IOError):
        """Error that triggers when we couldn't find the 'dig' binary"""

        def __init__(self, custommsg):
            if custommsg:
                self.msg = custommsg
            else:
                self.msg = self.message

        def __str__(self):
            return self.msg


def _check_if_dig_exists():
    try:
        for p in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
            if DEV_DEBUG_MODE:
                print "'dig' in %s: %s" % (p, os.path.exists(os.path.join(p, 'dig')))

            if os.path.exists(os.path.join(p, 'dig')):
                return

        raise _Errors.NoDigBinaryFound("Could not find dig on the system, check if $PATH is set correctly to "
                                       "include the directory containing dig executable.")
    except _Errors.NoDigBinaryFound as digerr:
        print "Attempting to run failed: %s" % str(digerr)
    except Exception as e:
        print "An unknown error occurred: %s" % str(e)


def _parse_arguments():
    # Parse Arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Use 'dig' with a TSIG key, with a default key unless otherwise specified.",
        add_help=False
    )
    optargs = parser.add_argument_group("Possible Arguments")
    optargs.add_argument('-h', required=False, action='store_true', default=False,
                         help="Show this help message and then exit.")
    optargs.add_argument('-k', metavar='keyfile', required=False, default=DEFAULT_TSIG_MD5_KEYFILE,
                         help='Specify the path to the keyfile for use with the signature. '
                              'Both {name}.key and {name}.private must exist to use this method. '
                              'If this is not specified, the default hardcoded location will be '
                              'used.')
    optargs.add_argument('args', metavar='STRING', nargs="*",
                         help="Any other 'dig' arguments or query string parameters.")

    parsed_arguments = parser.parse_args()

    if parsed_arguments.h:
        parser.print_help()
        exit()

    if DEV_DEBUG_MODE:
        print "Parsed Arguments: ", parsed_arguments

    return parsed_arguments


if __name__ == "__main__":
    _check_if_dig_exists()

    args = _parse_arguments()

    dig_args = ['dig', '-k']
    try:
        if args.k is not None:
            keypath = args.k
            if not str(keypath).__contains__('/'):
                keypath = CURRENT_WORKING_DIR + keypath

            if DEV_DEBUG_MODE:
                print "KEYPATH: ", keypath

            if not (os.path.exists(keypath + '.key') and os.path.exists(keypath + '.private')):
                raise _Errors.KeyfilePathIssue("Specified keyfile pair does not exist, "
                                               "check specified path, and ensure .key and "
                                               ".private files exist.")

            dig_args.append(keypath)

        if args.args:
            for arg in args.args:
                dig_args.append(arg)

    except _Errors.KeyfilePathIssue as err:
        print "An error occurred: %s" % err.__str__()
        exit()
    except Exception as err:
        print "An unknown error occurred: %s" % err.__str__()
        exit()

    if DEV_DEBUG_MODE:
        print dig_args

    # noinspection PyBroadException
    try:
        subprocess.call(dig_args)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, RuntimeError):
        exit()
    except Exception as e:
        print "An unknown error occurred: " % str(e)
        exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

To quote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501134/667648):

> `exit` is a helper for the interactive shell - `sys.exit` is intended for use in programs.

You should switch your `exit()` calls to `sys.exit()`.

Comment: Better yet, structure the code so that the program ends naturally, and you don't have to call `sys.exit()` at all (unless you want to exit with a non-zero status).

Answer (score 2):

Excpetions already support a custom error message out-of-the-box.

You can just do:

```
class KeyfilePathIssue(IOError):
    """Error that triggers only when an issue occurred with regards to the specified keyfile"""
    pass
```

And use it like you already do:

```
raise KeyfilePathIssue("Specified keyfile pair does not exist, "
                       "check specified path, and ensure .key and "
                       ".private files exist.")
```

There also seems to be no need for the `_Error` class holding the custom exceptions, it is obvious from their use and name that they are exceptions.

For a function named `_check_if_dig_exists` I would expect it to return `True` or `False` and only raise an exception if something unexpected happens. I would also rename it to `dig_exists`.

```
def dig_exists():
    try:
        for p in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
            if DEV_DEBUG_MODE:
                print "'dig' in %s: %s" % (p, os.path.exists(os.path.join(p, 'dig')))

            if os.path.exists(os.path.join(p, 'dig')):
                return True
        return False
    except Exception as e:
        print "An unknown error occurred: %s" % str(e)
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not dig_exists():
        raise NoDigBinaryFound("Could not find dig on the system, check if $PATH is set correctly to include the directory containing dig executable.")
    ...
```

The main code has also become big enough to put it into a `main` function and just call that in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block.